# Could not create developer portal in APIGEE

Tags: portal, apigee

I tried to create a developer community using URL : http://apigee.com/docs/content/developer-services-portal-request but Apigee did not respond with a developer portal URL. I had already created an organization. The organization name is **balajir**. Please let me know how to create a developer portal from Apigee tool. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Developer portals are not supported for Developer (free) accounts.  This is a recent change.  Our documentation will be updated to reflect this shortly.  If you are an Apigee Edge customer, this is supported.  If that is the case, contact Customer Support through the Support Portal and this will be taken care of quickly.